# Why Can't I delete Minecraft Files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ever since I downloaded, & put on the Spahx PureBD Craft, Minecraft stays on the start screen (Mojang). It will stay on for about 10 minutes & then minecraft will crash. So I wanted to delete minecraft. I found the .minecraft file & tried to delete it . But it says it can't delete because its used in a program. So, I deleted the desktop icon & tried again. Still didn't work. How do I get it to work?

Comment: When Minecraft crashed it didn't let go control of those files, so they can't be deleted. Reboot, then delete the `.minecraft` folder.

Comment: I just got this computer( Toshiba Satellite) a while ago, & so I'm not sure how to reboot . Unless Im just stupid & that means restart. Lol .

Comment: Restart, reboot, yes, it's the same.