# How do you uninstall Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open the game, the screen stays at the Mojang sign and then crashes. It has something to do with my texture pack, but I can't start the game to change it and it won't let me delete the texture pack folder alone.

I've already deleted the bin and resources folders in the minecraft folder and downloaded the game again. I opened it but the same problem was still there.

How do I properly perform a clean uninstall of the game?

Comment: Though this is very similar in some ways to your other question, this is a good question that hasn't been asked before! (Aside, you might want to [merge your accounts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge), since you seem to have created another one to ask this question.)

Answer (score 13):

To cleanly uninstall Minecraft you need to remove the entire `.minecraft` folder. If you want to keep your worlds, move the `saves` folder somewhere else before deleting the folder. You can always drop it back in once you reinstall Minecraft and run it once to re-create the `.minecraft` folder.

(The program you click isn't really Minecraft itself – it's just the launcher. You can get rid of it too if you want, but deleting it or not is separate from uninstalling Minecraft itself. It doesn't keep any settings or matter much, since it's just a convenience for launching the actual Minecraft program, which is stored in `.minecraft`. In fact, if you know how, you can start Minecraft without it entirely.)

---

In particular, I think your texture pack options are causing the crash. I've had that happen before, with an old texture pack crashing the game after I updated it.

I suspect that because, from [your other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111894/why-cant-i-delete-minecraft-files), it sounds like you were trying to use a 128x texture pack and it was crashing it. By choosing it, that choice is saved in your `options.txt` file in your `.minecraft` folder – deleting `bin` and `resources` will leave that intact! This option is probably what's crashing Minecraft. (Texture packs that are incompatible with the current version of Minecraft, or which are too large for your computer to handle well, can sometimes crash Minecraft.)

To fix it, open `options.txt` (using a text editor) and find the line that begins with `skin:`. It should say "spahx" or something like that. Change the line to:

> skin:Default

And then run Minecraft. It should work now, no un/re-install needed.

Answer (score 4):

Super simple steps to "uninstall" Minecraft:

1. Push `[Win]+R`, type in `%appdata%` in the Run field and hit enter.
2. One of the first folders is the `.minecraft` folder. Delete it.
3. Go to [Minecraft's Download page](http://minecraft.net/download) and get yourself a fresh copy of the game.

Keep in mind this deletes everything, including all locally saved games, texture packs, and customized settings/options.

Comment: Downloading a fresh copy of the launcher (the thing you download from minecraft.net) isn't necessary. Just re-run the launcher you already have, since not only is it the launcher, it's also the installer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sorry, was confused.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is delete your `.minecraft` folder and your minecraft launcher.

To get to the `.minecraft` directory do: <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `%appdata%` and it should appear there.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

- According to [this link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/29083-how-to-uninstall-minecraft/), you have to look for the folder

  > C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft

  and delete its contents. This option seems to be confirmed by [this link](http://solidlystated.com/software/how-to-uninstall-minecraft/).
- I had found another link that suggested to fiddle with REGEDIT.exe, but I usually try to avoid tweaking the Windows register.
- Another thing you can do is search for some [software uninstaller](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=software%20uninstaller) or [program cleaner](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=program%20cleaner) on the web, and see if one of those helps you out.

Comment: You just need to delete the .minecraft folder.  There is no need to use a third party software program, which is extremely unlikely to know about the files that Minecraft uses.  (Also, your REGEDIT link points back to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. After I have accidentally clicked fullscreen on in video settings, the game crashed. When I tried to log back in it said minecraft error.

Here are the steps to get that fixed on a pc:

1. Go to the bottom left Microsoft start button (red, green, blue, and yellow flag) at the main page
2. At the start search, type in %appdata%
3. Click "roaming"
4. Click on the minecraft file ".minecraft" (this is just a storage file)
5. Drag the saves file to your main screen wall
6. Go back to the .minecraft file and delete it
7. You can now log on to your minecraft. First it will update, but then you would see that you have no worlds (it's ok)
8. Exit out and go back to .minecraft, it will be back, and then click on it
9. Delete the new "saves" in .minecraft and then drag the old "saves" from your dashboard into your .minecraft folder
10. Click on Minecraft to play and you will see that all your worlds are there!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well for windows you're going to want to click the windows icon and type in *%appdata%* into the Windows Search Box, then locate your .minecraft folder. Delete the folder and you've uninstalled minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

I was having troubles with it too, but i couldn't find the .minecraft folder because I had deleted it ages ago and replaced it, so to those with the same problem, go to the start menu > look up 'run' > it'll bring you to a something like C:\programs blah blah blah %appdata%. here is where you will find the real .minecraft folder, delete it and you will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

A really easy way to get to the Minecraft folder is to type this in the search box: `%appdata%\.minecraft`. This ensures you get into the correct appdata folder.

Another really easy way to uninstall Minecraft is to use the Minecraft installer and press uninstall. Try to use repair first. I'm pretty sure you have to pay to get Minecraft back though.